# Invalid instruction operands (A2070)

Tags: ассемблер, masm32

У меня есть переменная размером 10 байт `size db 10 dup(?)`. Туда заносится любое число, вплоть до 10 байт, я пытаюсь сравнить эту переменную с числом `20000000h`, но почему-то не выходит.

Вот код: `cmp size, 20000000h` и выдаёт `Invalid instruction operands`

Хотя с более маленькими числами всё работает, почему так происходит?

Даже урезание переменной `size` до 8 байт не работает

Comment: Вы объявили массив байт, а не число. Я подозреваю, что у вас там не число, а набор символов, считанных с клавиатуры, например. Нужно сначала этот набор символов преобразовать в число (чем-то типа функции sscanf), потом уже число сравнивать с число (сейчас вы по сути сравниваете один первый байт с большим числом, явно превосходящий значение допустимое для байта). Ну или покажите как у вас в size попадают данные.

Comment: Используется функция, которая возвращает значение в числовом виде, и я заношу это число в переменную и пытаюсь сравнить с числом 20000000h

Comment: Добавьте пример, в каком именно виде у вас приходят числа. Все данные в компьютере хранятся в числовом виде, поэтому "числовой вид" не говорит ни о чем. Либо добавьте в вопрос саму функцию, тогда возможно станет понятнее.

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, потому что данных в вопросе по сути недостаточно для ответа.

Answer (score 0):

архитектура процессоров не позволяет сравнивать числа произвольной длины, сравнить можно только (байт / слово / двойное слов / восемь байт). все что больше восьми байт это длинная арифметика которая может быть выполнена лишь серией команд.

либо придумай как сократить длину до восьми байт либо учи длинную арифметику, которая сразу гораздо сложней.